# Jenkins can't install plugins - windows 10

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I want to install Test Ng results plugin to Jenkins. But manage plugins showing below error & cant search any plugins there.. Any help would be appreciable..

[image]

Comment: are you facing same issue with available tab also. because if you want to install anything, you need to search on available tab. if you are using cloud instance check the security group or firewall, if anything blocks the plugins

Comment: Are you behind f/w? Proxy in Advanced tab.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have internet connectivity from the host server where Jenkins is installed.
Also for the new plugin, you will need to check in 'Available' tab.

If there is connectivity issue, you have an option to do offline installation.

1) Download the plugin file and put it in directory "JenkinsHomeFolder/plugins/" (if not sure about the folder, Go to services.msc, check properties of Jenkins service)

2) Restart the Jenkins service.